# OO Design & Core Data: Where to put aggregate calculation method?

Tags: objective-c, ios, oop, core-data

I have a `NSManagedObject company` with the properties `(NSString*) name` and `(NSDate*) lastAvailableInterim`.

I would like to calculate aggregate values for an array of companies (`NSArray *companies`), for instance the last reporting date which equals the end of a quarter based on the following code sample:

```
- (NSDate*)latestAvailableInterimFor:(NSArray*)companies
{   // returns the maximum interim report date for all companies in the selection, date has to have end month = quarter end
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    __block NSDate *maxLatestAvailableInterim;

    [self.companies enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(IBCompany *company, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSDateComponents *monthComponents = [gregorian components:NSMonthCalendarUnit fromDate:company.latestAvailableInterim];
        NSAssert((company.latestAvailableInterim),@"LatestAvailableInterim must be <> NIL!");
        NSInteger month = [monthComponents month];
        if ( month % 3 == 0 ) maxLatestAvailableInterim = MAX(maxLatestAvailableInterim, company.latestAvailableInterim);
    }];
    return maxLatestAvailableInterim;
}
```

From a **object oriented perspective** and based on the **MVC** scheme, where would I put this code?

In the view controller, which handles the result value or "near" the `(NSManagedObject*) company` subclass or would it make sense to add a category to `NSArray`?

Thank you!

Comment: i suspect it should go in the model.

Comment: From a mvc perspective, you should make it into a model. As Ray Stated. self.companies should be the "companies" parameter of the method instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a category to NSArray. You can add a class method to your IBCompany class that receives an NSManagedObjectContext and uses it to perform a fetch to find the right date you are looking for. Try to do the finding of the right date via an NSFetchRequest instead of doing in-memory check.

You can also do it in the view controller that handles the resulting information.

Comment: You mean adding a class method like `+ (NSDate*)lastReportedInterimFor:(NSArray*)companies`to `NSManagedObject *company`? Good point regarding fetching the right date using an `NSFetchRequest`, but how can I evaluate an date's month in a fetch request?

Comment: You can create a date the last date of the previous month and the first date of the next month and find the companies with a date between those dates. The method would look like this + (NSDate*)lastReportedInterim; Since you are returning a date, you can create a NSManagedObjectContext inside that class method to do the fetching. This way, the method can be safely used from different threads.